# rsync over ssh delete existing files

Tags: file, ssh, rsync, delete-file

I am trying to get files from a Server on my Raspberry Pi with rsync over ssh.
Right now i'm using this (it works):

```
rsync -avz -e ssh USER@SERVER:'/server/directory' '/traget/directory'
```

Files that are not on the server anymore should now be deleted on the RP.
How do I do that? (--delete seems not to work)

Comment: Why is delete not working? You can first delete and then sync.

Comment: I am dumb... I put delete at the wrong place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more option, presuming that you have permissions to delete files under `/traget/directory`:

```
     --delete                delete extraneous files from destination dirs
```

Also watch out for typos when executing commands that can delete files and directories!

Comment: Oh I just tried again with --delete and it works now... I just put --delete in the wrong place.

Comment: What is the right place to put --delete? I'm having trouble with it myself

Comment: @EricWolf: `rsync -avz --delete -e ssh USER@SERVER:'/server/directory' '/traget/directory'`